# Generating first 50 positive integers, divisible by 7

Tags: c, for-loop

The logic I've been using to comprehend `loops` doesn't appear consistent.

The code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    int n,i;
    printf("\n Integer divisible by 7 \n");
    n = 7;
    for(i = 1; i<=50; i++) {
        printf("%8d", n);
        n = n + 7;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
Integers divisible by 
7 14 21 35 42 49 56 63 70
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 343 350
```

How is the number `7` still printing if the statement `n = n +7` already increases `n`'s value by 7?

Comment: Because the line `n = n + 7` comes ***after*** the line `printf(…)` - what would you think should happen?

Comment: And `7` is divisible by `7`.

Comment: I *would* have thought that 14 gets printed first

Comment: `c` programming language is `sequential`. One line is executd after the other. So from your code, it says "display value of n" then "update value of n"

Comment: Thank you @PhoenixBlue! Helps a great deal. Extended to @Adrian also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works like this:

```
n = 7;
for(i = 1; i<=50; i++) // is i less than 50? If yes go inside for
{
    printf("%8d", n);  // print n (the first time it's still 7)
    n = n + 7;         // increase n by 7
}
```

As you can see you print the value of n before increasing it the first time, this means that since n was initially 7 you print that value.

If you want to exclude 7 from the prints you should either move the print below `n = n + 7` or make `n` equal to 14 instead of 7 but still increase it by 7 inside the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
int n,i;
printf("\n Integer divisible by 7 \n");
n = 7;
for(i = 1; i<=50; i++)
{
  // when you print n here the first time it still has the value 7
  printf("%8d", n); 

  n = n + 7;
}
return 0;
```

If you want to increment your n value before print, just do

```
n = n+7;
// then
printf("%8d", n);
```